# Is there any way such that wifi never goes to sleep in iPhone 4S. Is that Some thing can I do by coding?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

My application is continuously running in background and send's user location  every 10 minutes. I am testing my application in iPhone 4S. Application is running good in background but the the problem is that after some time my wifi goes to sleep and application starts sending user location via sim network.

Is there any way such that wifi never goes to sleep in iPhone 4S. Is that Some thing can I do by coding?

Comment: How can the wifi go to sleep ??? seriously ?

Comment: Thank you M Hasan for editing.

Comment: Yes, Gil you can check the device log, wifi goes to sleep by giving wifi status 0 in log.

Comment: I think that wifi turning off after some while is a good thing so it will not drain the battery and surely if this is how apple configured the iOS I doubt you can prevent it from happening. You could however use reachability and if wifi is not available stop sending location untill wifi is available again.